# Xcode: iPad keyboard troubles (not that simple)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, view, keyboard, ipad

I am making an app which uses many Textfields. Most of them are inside static tableViews. I use the split view application template. Every category selected from the left panel presents a storyboard scene inside a second view on the right panel. 
I just want to get rid of the keyboard with the "done" button however everything i have tried that would work on a simple view fails to work under these circumstances. 
Can you please help me out with this?

p.s. I try to dismiss the keyboard inside the implementation file of the presented storyboard scene. Should i do something inside the Detail Scene of the split view controller?

Here is my Scene's code:

```
.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @interface AfoEsoda : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *merismataTF;
    -(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender;
    @end

.m
@synthesize merismataTF;

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            merismataTF.delegate=self ;
        }

//---------Hide Keyboard-------------------
//Tried but didn't work
-(IBAction)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [merismataTF resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
//Of course i do not use both methods at the same time.
```

EDIT:
When i set the textfield's delegate to self i get this crash:
[image: textfieldShouldReturn Crach]

Comment: I tried the "resign first responder" and the "textfieldshouldreturn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the textField's delegate, set the delegate to self, and in the delegate's method

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

set

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Another way could be going through all of the view's subviews and if it is a text field, resign first responder:

```
for(int i=0;i<self.view.subviews.count;i++)
{
if([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
{
    if([[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isFirstResponder])
         [[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:i] resignFirstResponder];
}}
```

OK, I got it. Use this with with the textFieldShouldReturn method.
So here is your answer: You have declared your text field as a property and then use alloc and init it over and over again for each cell. Probably it only works properly for the last row.

Here is an example of how your cellForRow method should look like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"My cell identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UITextField *newTextField;
if(cell == nil)
 {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  newTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(0,0,25,25)];
  newTextField.tag = 1;
  newTextField.delegate = self;
  [cell.contentView addSubview:newTextField];
  }
  else
     newTextField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
```

And then, if you need the textField's value for a certaing row, simply use:

```
UITextField *someTextField = (UITextField *)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView viewWithTag:1];
NSLog(@"textField.text = %@", someTextField.text);
```

Comment: When i do it your way it crashes when i touch the textfield. See screenshot above.

Comment: please add the header and implementation files to the post.

Comment: I just did. Thanks for your time!

Comment: See if the other way works for you. Please also add the cellForRow atIndexPath method

Comment: @PantelisProios I have update my answer and it should work now. However, I must say that the best way to create a custom cell is to subclass it and then use that subclass for your cell. It's easier, safer and a better practice.